# Angular 7 production build (AOT) with arrow functions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, aot

I work now for 3 years with Angular JS and Angular 2+ (hybrid application) and experiment now with the Angular CLI.
I think I know pretty much about JIT and AOT.

https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

...says, that "the AOT compiler does not support function expressions and arrow functions".
The "ng build --prod" will build the application with AOT.

My scenario:

I created a new project, implemented an arrow function, which console.log something. If I build the application with "ng build --prod", the application works fine (started from /dist folder) and the console.log prints. I also analyzed it with webpack bundle analyzer and there is no compiler in the bundle or other things (like an AOT application).

My question:

So, how does the application work? Why does this arrow function work? Why the "ng build --prod" prints no errors?

I think I have a board in front of my head.

Comment: Can you give us an example of how you wrote arrow function?

Comment: Did you stop reading the doc after the sentence you quote? Seems like all the information you need is there. Like this: *The AOT collector does not support the arrow function, () => new Server(), **in a metadata expression.***

Comment: Actually that documentation tells about metadata but if you will read further then you can see `Beginning in version 5, the compiler automatically performs this rewriting while emitting the .js file.` So called Lower Expressions transformer does it for us

Comment: Oh damn "metadata expression". I am sorry. :D Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The AOT collector does not support the arrow function, () => new Server(), in **a metadata expression.** Thanks to @R.Richards.

Comment: **Beginning in version 5, the compiler automatically performs this rewriting while emitting the .js file**

Answer (score 0):

the following syntax will work and will not give any error in **AOT**

```
arrowFun = () => { };
```

but as per doc its for **metadata expression**

> The AOT collector does not support the arrow function, () => new
> Server(), in a metadata expression. It generates an error node in
> place of the function. When the compiler later interprets this node,
> it reports an error that invites you to turn the arrow function into
> an exported function.

You can read it [here](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#no-arrow-functions)

From the doc

The AOT compiler does not support function expressions and arrow functions, also called lambda functions.

Consider the following component decorator:

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [{provide: server, useFactory: () => new Server()}]
})
```

this will throw an error, to fix this you can use

```
export function serverFactory() {
  return new Server();
}

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [{provide: server, useFactory: serverFactory}]
})
```

**In version 5 and later, the compiler automatically performs this rewriting while emitting the .js file.**